# click the bottom part of an element?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a link that I need to click on that is halfway underneath another element.  Something like this:

```
______________________
| A  ____________    | <-- on top
|____|B_________|____|
     |__________| < - on bottom (need to click this one)
```

When I try to click on the bottom link, I get

```
(B) is not clickable at point (254, 5). Other element would receive the click: (A).
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPPsN.jpg) is an image (I need to click on the PO Box link).  I don't know exactly what to do here.  Thanks!

Here is the HTML in question.  Selenium is sending the click action to the span `labelFieldWrapper`:

```
<div class='clr type_address formFieldContainer'>
    <span class="labelFieldWrapper">
        <label class="placeholder" for="address1">
            <span class="labelText">Address 1</span>
        </label>
        <input id="address1" name="address1" type="text" value="" autofillparam="ON" size="20" maxlength="60"/><span class="asterisk">*</span>
    </span>
    <p class="helpLink">
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" 
           onclick="window.open('/checkout/canadian_province_support.jsp',
          'pobox', 
          'width=450, \
           height=200, \
           directories=no, \
           location=no, \
           menubar=no, \
           resizable=no, \
           scrollbars=1, \
           status=no, \
           toolbar=no'); 
          return false;">PO Box?</a>  <-- Trying to click on this link
        </p>
    </div><!-- /formFieldContainer -->
```

Comment: I think the only way out is `Actions` class. Thanks

Comment: How would I do that?  I've only used `Actions` for hover actions before.

Comment: It would be a bit tricky to click on the intended element. Can you share the url incase it's a public url? Do mention the manual steps for reference. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if this case you can make some workaround, like click on the bottom of element

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("someXpath"));
int halfOfHeight = element.getSize().getHeight()/2;
// moveToElement* method moves to the middle of element, so we'll also move on half of element and click on the 3rd pix from the bottom
int offset = halfOfHeight - 3; 

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions
       .moveToElement(element)
       .moveByOffset(0, offset)
       .click()
       .build()
       .perform();
```

Comment: Yes!  That did it!  I tried adding `10` to the `yOffSet` in the `.moveToElement` method, but that didn't work.  Adding `.moveByOffset` did work.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably `.moveToElement` with `yOffSet` could help too, but it will start from the top of element, so you should do same, just not divide height on 2 =)

Answer (score 1):

This mostly happens in Chrome. Chrome does not calculate the exact location of element and always click in the middle of Element.

To fix this, get the element coordinate and then click on the link

> ```
> WebElement link= driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of link"));
> ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+link.getLocation().x+")");
> link.click();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use
xpath= `//p[@class="helpLink"]/a`

Comment: That doesn't work.  Targeting the element isn't the issue, it's that selenium clicks the top element instead of the PO Box link.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look at the problem in a broader way and implement a method to click anywhere on the element. The below is the code snippet. I wrote the below in C# and successfully able to test.
The x and y co-ordinates are assigned with respect to element size which makes it easier to perform the action on the element.

You can implement a method ClickElementAt and call the method like below.

```
ClickElementAt(element,Bottom);//Calling the method here

//Implementation
  public void ClickElementAt(Element element, ClickPoint clickPoint)
    {
        int x, y;

        switch (clickPoint)
        {
            case ClickPoint.Center:
                x = element.Size.Width / 2;
                y = element.Size.Height / 2;
                break;
            case ClickPoint.Top:
                x = element.Size.Width / 2;
                y = element.Size.Height / 10;
                break;
            case ClickPoint.Left:
                x = element.Size.Width / 10;
                y = element.Size.Height / 2;
                break;
            case ClickPoint.Right:
                x = element.Size.Width * 90 / 100;
                y = element.Size.Height / 2;
                break;
            case ClickPoint.Bottom:
                x = element.Size.Width / 2;
                y = element.Size.Height * 90 / 100;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("clickPoint");
        }

        var actions = new Actions(this.driver);
        actions
            .MoveToElement(element, x, y)
            .Click()
            .Perform();
    }
```