# How can I click a button that's only clickable from the bottom half?

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

So I'm trying to hit this button to activate the dropdown menu, but it seems that only half of it works, Im afraid the automation is clicking the top bottom or somewhere where is not active, let me illustrate with a few screenshots, which will contain a comparisson. ALSO can I click on one of the options from the dropdown without "activating it"? (clicking the DropDown Button)

[image: Issue-NotClickable]

[image: Issue-Clickable]

Now another example from the button fully working

[image: WorkingAsExpected1]

[image: WorkingAsExpected2]

I have found that the button fully works if it's the first one to be clicked, if I click something else, then this issue happens, and that's only button with this issue

Comment: kind of looks like that's by design... meaning the pulldown will populate with choices only after another selection is made.  The click() function of Selenium will click in the center of the element... but if the site has made the top-half intentionally unclickable, that seems like a bug that should be written up.  (You can use actions to define an offset and click if needed... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375378/click-the-bottom-part-of-an-element )

Comment: @pcalkins I copied the most voted answer's code, still had to do the action twice to make it work, don't know what's wrong with it, but since it's only me automating this process, I doubt they would even listen to me, thanks a lot, it did help me.